# October CMS Validation on Update

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I have a Users model with the following

```
public $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|between:2,64|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required:create|between:2,32|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password|between:2,32'
];
```

I'm trying to update the model with a new value

```
$user->auth_token = $token->authToken;
$user->save();
```

on save however I am getting validation errors since the model is expecting a email, password and password confirmation. I have tried to add `sometimes|` to the validation but that doesn't seem to work. I've also used `$user->forceSave()` which works but it seems like a work around to the actual issue. Any thoughts on how to go about updating a single field without triggering validation?

Comment: And how did you get the `$user` instance?, actually if you are getting a record from the database the `email,password` they have to be filled by default

Comment: Where are you defining these rules? In what file?

Comment: I'm searching the db for the username by email $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

Comment: These rules are defined on the model as per october cms standard I believe. So in my case I have a User.php

Answer (score 1):

I am going from the assumption you don't want validation on object creation only on update.

By adding this method to your model that uses `October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation` you disable validation for objects that are being created.

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    if(!$this->exists) {
        $this->rules = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [octobercms docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#overriding-validation) using `$user->forceSave()` is the correct way to bypass the validation.